# Use the Residue Theorem to evaluate the integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Use the Residue Theorem to evaluate the integrals:

i) $$ \int_{|z-\frac{1}{2}|=1} \frac{e^{4z}}{z^2(z+1)^2}dz$$

**My attempt:** 
$2\pi i res(0)+2\pi i res(-1) $

$res(-1)=0$ vanishes since $-1$ is clearly not in the interior of the curve ${|z-\frac{1}{2}|=1}$

$res(0)=\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{e^{4z}}{(z+1)^2})=\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{4e^{4z}z+2e^{4z}}{(z+1)^3} $

$=   \frac{4e^{4*0}*0+2e^{4*0}}{(0+1)^3}$

$=   \frac{2e^{0}}{(0+1)^3}=2=>res(0)=2$

Thus,

$\int_{|z-\frac{1}{2}|=1} \frac{e^{4z}}{(z^2(z+1)^2)} dz = 2\pi i res(0)=2 \pi i *2=4 \pi i$ (my answer: not sure if I'm correct here...)

ii) $$\int_{|z=1|} z^{m}\cos(\frac{1}{z})dz, $$$m=0,1,2,...$ (got no idea how to do this...)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to number 1 looks fine. For part ii, series expand
$$
\cos(1/z)=1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{4!}\frac{1}{z^4}+....
$$
Then your integral becomes
$$\int_{|z=1|} z^{m}\cos(\frac{1}{z})dz=
\int_{|z=1|} z^{m}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\frac{1}{z^{2n}}dz\\
=\int_{|z=1|} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\frac{1}{z^{2n-m}}dz$$
Then use the residue theorem after solving for the coefficient on $1/z$ (the only term that gives your integral weight) by figuring out when (and if) $2n-m=1\Rightarrow 2n=1+m$.

This final condition tells you that your integral is zero for $m$ even and for $m$ odd, the integral has value 
$$
-\frac{2\pi i}{(m+1)!}
$$
by the residue theorem.